# importing modules installed globally with 'npm' in ts-node files

Tags: node.js, ts-node

I am very new to all this `Node` and `TypeScript` stuff so if I'm doing anything not the way it should be done, feel free to comment on my approach.

I'm trying to play around with `RxJS` and would like to be able to write some code and have it run on the command line, without having to write a HTML page and fire up a browser. I installed `nvm` with `Homebrew` and through it I installed `node 10.11.0` and can successfully use it:

```
$ which node
/Users/wujek/.nvm/versions/node/v10.11.0/bin/node
$ node -e 'console.log("Hello, world!")'
Hello, world!
```

I would like to use `TypeScript` to write my code, so I installed it globally (version 3.0.3) via `npm` and it works - I can write a basic `.ts` file and have it transpiled to `.js` using `tsc` on the command line.

I would like to run `.ts` files on the command line and I found `ts-node` and installed it globally (version 7.0.1) via `npm`. No I can run simple files:

```
$ ts-node <(echo 'class Foo{}; console.log(new Foo());')
Foo {}
```

As the last step I globally installed `RxJS` (version 6.3.3) via `npm` and tried all of it together, and here it fails at the import line:

```
$ echo 'import { Observable } from "rxjs";' > rx.ts
$ ts-node rx.ts

/Users/wujek/.nvm/versions/node/v10.11.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
       ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
rx.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
(and the error stack trace)
```

I didn't start any project or anything, I just installed the tools, wrote source files and fired the tools up.

Coming from other platforms, like Python, I would expect the globally installed modules to be available, but they are not (or I am importing them wrong, maybe the syntax for `Node` should be different?). How can I make it work? I would prefer not to fire up a fully blown IDE like VS-Code (I wouldn't even know how to make the code run anyway) as I would like to start humble and simple at the CLI.

Comment: This isn't a good way of working, RxJS isn't designed to be consumed like that anyway. You need a package.json in your cwd and then you could link the global packages but that's not likely worth it.

Comment: Ok, so what would the best way of working for me be? Let me just mention what I would do in Python: I would just create a virtualenv, install the package I want to play around with in it, just start the REPL or write some code in a file and run it. I was looking for a similar work flow here as well. I am aware this is not a good approach for big projects, but I just want to get my hands dirty quickly, for basic evaluation.